# Compiled, can't access with sudo

Tags: compiling, root, path, executable

So I compiled FFmpeg from [this](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide) guide as a standard user and it works fine as the user I compiled with but if i do `sudo ffmpeg` the program can't be found. Is it possible to make it accessible by root or do I need to rebuild logged in as root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `ffmpeg` has not been placed in a directory that is in root's [`$PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). The guide you linked to (in the future please include the steps here so we don't need to go looking for them) tells you to run this command:

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin"
```

This will cause `ffmpeg`'s files to be installed into `$HOME/ffmpeg_build` and the compiled executable into `$HOME/bin` (in the `make install` step). If you can run it as your normal user, that means that you have modified your `$PATH` and have added that directory to it.

For root to run it you can either add `/home/your_user/bin` to roots path or, much better, just call `sudo` and give the path to the executable:

```
sudo ~/bin/ffmpeg
```